# Copy objects in google cloud objects started to fail

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I have a class that copies objects in google cloud storage and suddenly stopped working yesterday.

It looks like a client error, but I have absolute no idea what the issue could be.

Attached you will find the screenshot with all relevant information. It is from an integration test that tests the abstraction to google cloud storage.

My sample to reproduce it: https://gist.github.com/SebastianStehle/ff8315f724f14c3e805e8986eff0f1ad

An even simpler sample to reproduce it:

```
using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace GCETest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bucket = "squidex-test";
            var objectStream = new MemoryStream(new byte[] { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4 });
            var objectName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            var storageClient = StorageClient.Create();

            storageClient.UploadObject(bucket, objectName, "application/octet-stream", objectStream);
            storageClient.CopyObject(bucket, objectName, bucket, $"{objectName}_Copy");
        }
    }
}
```

The full exception:

```
The service storage has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Invalid argument [400]
Errors [
    Message[Invalid argument] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]
]

   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.CopyObject(String sourceBucket, String sourceObjectName, String destinationBucket, String destinationObjectName, CopyObjectOptions options)
   at GCETest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\mail2\source\repos\AzureTest\AzureTest\Program.cs:line 18
```

It started yesterday, I think, and has always happened since then and not only on this bucket.

[image: Copy]

Comment: Does this happen every time, or just intermittently? Are you able to reproduce it in a small console app? (Note that it would be easier for most readers if you could include the source code and the exception message as text in the question - leaving the screenshot as well if you feel that's helpful.)

Comment: Please read [ask], provide a [mcve] and share your research.

Comment: You are right, I have added a small sample.

Comment: Could I suggest that you try to minimize that to just one method? It looks like most of the methods you call are a single statement each, so that should be easy to do. You might want to try using the sync calls just to make the stack traces simpler, too. Once it's nice and simple, it would be best to include the code directly in the question rather than as a link. Could you also indicate whether this always happens, or just intermittently?

Comment: Done, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Great, thanks. I've reproduced it myself and I'm going to dig into it more tomorrow. I've asked a colleague on the GCS team to look at it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug in the client library, in terms of its handling of the `RewriteToken` part of the `RewriteObjectResponse`. We were assuming it would not be set when the operation was complete, and it appears that recently it started being set to an empty string instead.

We have fixed the code to use the `Done` property instead, and released two new versions of the `Google.Cloud.Storage.V1` package:

- Version 2.3.0-beta04 is the latest prerelease package
- Version 2.2.1 is available for users who need to stay on GA versions